# Simplify and reduce the amount of code without using macros

Tags: c, optimization, coding-style, macros

Sometimes, there are situations where the repetition of simple code blocks is unavoidable. To illustrate, with this example code:

*Note: this code is for illustration purpose only, real-life code is much bigger and more complex. Also it may contain errors, but the point of this question is not that.*

```
switch(cmd) {
    case CMD_BLOCK_READ:
        if(current_user != key) {
            ERROR("Access violation - invalid key!");
            res = CR_ACCESS_DENIED;
            break; 
        }
        if(current_state < STATE_BUSY) {
            WARN("Command %s is not allowed in this state!", cmd_name[cmd]);
            res = CR_NOT_PERMITTED;
            break;
        }
        if(ioctl(fd, HPI_CTL_BR) != 0) {
            WARN("Handshake failed (%s). Aborted!", strerror(errno));
            res = CR_TIME_OUT;
            goto post_resp;
        }
        if(block_read(id) != 0) {
            ERROR("Failed to read %d block (%s)! Aborted!", id, strerror(errno));
            res = CR_FAIL;
            goto send_nop;
        }

        res = CR_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case CMD_BLOCK_WRITE:
        if(current_user != key) {
            ERROR("Access violation - invalid key!");
            res = CR_ACCESS_DENIED;
            break; 
        }
        if(current_state < STATE_BUSY) {
            WARN("Command %s is not allowed in this state!", cmd_name[cmd]);
            res = CR_NOT_PERMITTED;
            break;
        }
        if(ioctl(fd, HPI_CTL_BR) != 0) {
            WARN("Handshake failed (%s). Aborted!", strerror(errno));
            res = CR_TIME_OUT;
            goto post_resp;
        }
        if(block_write(id) != 0) {
            ERROR("Failed to write %d block - %s. Command aborted!", id, strerror(errno));
            res = CR_FAIL;
            goto send_nop;
        }
        res = CR_SUCCESS;
        break;
    case CMD_REQ_START:
        if(current_state < STATE_READY) {
            WARN("Command %s is not allowed in this state!", cmd_name[cmd]);
            res = CR_NOT_PERMITTED;
            break;
        }
        state = STATE_BUSY;
        if(ioctl(fd, HPI_CTL_BR) != 0) {
            WARN("Handshake failed (%s). Aborted!", strerror(errno));
            res = CR_TIME_OUT;
            goto send_nop;
        }
        if(block_read(id) != 0) {
            ERROR("Failed to read %d block (%s)! Aborted!", id, strerror(errno));
            res = CR_FAIL;
            goto post_resp;
        }
        res = CR_SUCCESS;
        break;
    }

    /* The remaining 28 or so similar commands */
}
```

As you can see, due to minor differences and the extensive use of *break/goto* statements, it is not possible to use functions or inlines. What I usually do is define some macros:

```
/* NOTE: DO NOT USE these macros outside of Big Switch */
#define CHECK_KEY(_key) \
   if(current_user != (_key)) \
   { \
      ERROR("Access violation!"); \
      res = CR_ACCESS_DENIED; \
      break; \
   }
#define CHECK_STATE(_state) \
   if(current_state < _state) \
   { \
      WARN("Command %s is not allowed in this state!", cmd_name[cmd]); \
      res = CR_NOT_PERMITTED; \
      break; \
   }

#define HANDSHAKE(_fail) \
   if(ioctl(fd, CTL_BR) != 0) \
   { \
      WARN("Handshake failed (%s). Aborted!", strerror(errno)); \
      res = CR_TIME_OUT; \
      goto _fail; \
   }

#define BLOCK_READ(_id, _fail) \
   if(block_read((int)(_id))!= 0) \
   { \
      ERROR("Failed to read %d block (%s)! Aborted!", (int)_id, strerror(errno)); \
      res = CR_FAIL; \
      goto _fail; \
   }

#define BLOCK_WRITE(_id, _fail) \
   if(block_write((int)(_id)) != 0) \
   { \
      ERROR("Failed to write %d block - %s. Aborted!", (int)_id, strerror(errno)); \
      res = CR_FAIL; \
      goto _fail; \
   }
```

..and write the same code using them. The code becomes **much** smaller and (arguably) more readable:

```
switch(cmd) 
{
case CMD_BLOCK_READ:
   CHECK_KEY(key);
   CHECK_STATE(STATE_BUSY);
   HANDSHAKE(post_resp);
   BLOCK_READ(id, send_nop);
   res = CR_SUCCESS;
   break;
case CMD_BLOCK_WRITE:
   CHECK_KEY(key);
   CHECK_STATE(STATE_BUSY);
   HANDSHAKE(post_resp);
   BLOCK_WRITE(id, send_nop);
   res = CR_SUCCESS;
   break;
case CMD_REQ_START:
{
   CHECK_STATE(STATE_READY);
   state = STATE_BUSY;
   HANDSHAKE(send_nop);
   BLOCK_READ(id, post_resp);
   res = CR_SUCCESS;
   break;
}
/* The remaining 28 or so similar commands */
<..>
```

The code looks more like some kind of scripting language than good old *C* and is really ugly, but I'm willing to sacrifice that for the sake of readability.

**The question** is how do you cope with similar situations? What are more elegant solutions and best practises?

**P.S.** I admit that in general case macros and *goto* statement is a sign of bad design, so no need to flame about how evil they are or how poor my programming style is.

Comment: At the very least, to prevent misuse of the macros, you should `#undef` them after your Big Switch.

Comment: More elegant solutions and best practices include avoiding macros and `goto` altogether. That's all I can think of.

Comment: defining function pointer and then array indexed on switch case would reduce the switch cases a lot.

Comment: @nneonneo they are defined in *.c* file, so no one should include them, but yes, I agree that it is a right thing to do. Will take your suggestion the next time I meet such a monster.

Comment: @rajneesh could you please elaborate more, and maybe even provide an example?

Comment: @rajneesh: It would reduce the switch, but you'd have an equivalent  amount of code in functions. It's just moving the problem around.

Comment: @netcoder: the question is about elegantly putting the logic, and not reducing the number of lines

Comment: @netcoder Where did you get such "best practices"? Macros and `goto` have their uses. Do not follow dogmas.

Comment: @qrdl: They have some uses, but those should be pretty rare. Hence the word *avoiding*.

Comment: @netcoder There are situations in C when macros and `goto` are better than any alternative. There is no widespread best practice to avoid these language features so it makes your comment incorrect.

Comment: @qrdl: I've also heard the opposite. So I guess this whole argument is pointless.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to claim that the Python source code is the paragon of organization, but it contains (IMHO) a good example of macros being used to simplify a complex piece of code.

The Python main loop implements a bytecode-executing stack-based VM. It contains a huge switch-case with one case for every opcode Python supports. The dispatch for an opcode looks like this:

```
case STORE_ATTR:
    w = GETITEM(names, oparg);
    v = TOP();
    u = SECOND();
    STACKADJ(-2);
    err = PyObject_SetAttr(v, w, u); /* v.w = u */
    Py_DECREF(v);
    Py_DECREF(u);
    if (err == 0) continue;
    break;
```

where `TOP`, `SECOND` and `STACKADJ` are all defined as macros operating on the stack object . Some macros have alternate `#define`s used to assist with debugging. All of the opcodes are written in this way, and it helps make the implementation of each opcode much clearer by expressing the logic in this sort of miniature scripting language.

In my view, careful, judicious and limited use of macros can improve code readability and make the logic clearer. In your case, where the macros hide some small but nontrivial functionality, it can be useful to have macros to standardize the implementation and ensure that you don't have multiple copies of the same snippets of code to update.

Comment: +1 for pointing to Python sources, I'll take a look into it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In such situations I usually consider whether the cases may be reasonably described with a data, which are then processed in a single common block of code. Sure it cannot be done always, but often it is possible.

In your case it might lead to something similar to the following:

```
#define IO_NOOP    0
#define IO_READ    1
#define IO_WRITE   2

struct cmd_desc { 
   int check_key;     /* non-zero to do a check */
   int check_state;
   int new_state;
   void* handshake_fail;
   int io_dir;
   void* io_fail;
};

const struct cmd_desc cmd_desc_list[] = {
   { 1, STATE_BUSY,  -1,         &&post_resp, IO_READ,  &&send_nop },  /* CMD_BLOCK_READ */
   { 1, STATE_BUSY,  -1,         &&post_resp, IO_WRITE, &&send_nop },  /* CMD_BLOCK_WRITE */
   { 0, STATE_READY, STATE_BUSY, &&send_nop,  IO_READ,  &&post_rep }   /* CMD_REQ_START */
};

const struct cmd_desc* cmd_desc = cmds[cmd];

if(cmd_desc->check_key) {
   if(current_user != key) {
      ERROR("Access violation - invalid key!");
      return CR_ACCESS_DENIED;
   }
}

if(cmd_desc->check_state != -1) {
   if(current_state check_state) {
      WARN("Command %s is not allowed in this state!", cmd_name[cmd]);
      return CR_NOT_PERMITTED;
   }
}

if(cmd_desc->new_state != -1)
   state = cmd_desc->new_state;

switch(cmd_desc->io_dir) {
   case IO_READ:
      if(block_read(id) != 0) {
         ERROR("Failed to read %d block (%s)! Aborted!", id, strerror(errno));
         res = CR_FAIL;
         goto *cmd_desc->io_fail;
      }
      break;

   case IO_WRITE:
      if(block_write(id) != 0) {
         ERROR("Failed to write %d block (%s)! Aborted!", id, strerror(errno));
         res = CR_FAIL;
         goto *cmd_desc->io_fail;
      }
      break;

   case IO_NOOP:
      break;
}

res = CR_SUCCESS;
```

Notes I used "Labels as Values" extension of gcc for the goto labels (http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html). In standard C you might use function pointers instead but that would require some reorganization of the code and I do not have enough info for that.

Comment: +1 as the command descriptor list is surely an interesting idea. Sadly, I may not be able to try your example in practice as I usually have to stick to the standard C.

Comment: With some more code reorganization if may be replaced with `if`s or function pointers (each small code block would have to be function). It's the core idea what matters, not exact way how it is achieved.

Answer (score 1):

With the code you posted, there is no reason you couldn't have used functions.  This would be the "Extract Function" refactoring pattern.  To handle the gotos, just leave them in your main function, and call them or not based on the function result.

http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/extractMethod.html

Also, you've really made a mess of things by using variables in the macros that are not passed in.  This means you can't reuse them easily and they are arguably worse than writing the whole thing long-hand.  If you passed in everything that is used by the macro, then it is more useful.  Then you get a duck-typing style coding, which can be used effectively.

Also, you are using C, so you shouldn't "avoid" macros.  They are incredibly useful, primarily for code generation.  (i.e. stringification and concatentation)  Many C++ and some other say "macros are evil".   This is C, macros are not evil.